# Sql tuning - Just need 5 records from table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
    select * 
    from customers 
    where column1 = 'test'
    limit 5;
```

I just need 5 records. will execution engine stop running after finding 5 records which matches condition.

I am working on table with millions of records simple select statement with limit is taking ~20 minutes.

Can I improve the performance of this query?

Comment: Do you really need `all` columns ?

Comment: Add `ORDER BY` clause - afair, without it all records are fetched internally before returning the dataset. The best choice if an index `(column1, column_in_order_by)` exists.

Comment: @JayaVenkat . . . Most databases would stop after five records, including the Postgres that underlies Redshift.  However, you may need to do some testing to satisfy that this is really happening.  If you have an `ORDER BY`, all the data needs to be processed so the `LIMIT` won't have much impact.

Comment: set up column1 as the sortkey, make sure you have a sensible distkey.

Comment: Performance in this case depends on multiple factors. Redshift is column-oriented database, so column count in select statement affects performance. Millions of records is not much for Redshift. I would also suggest to review encoding of columns and set up sensible sortkey and distkey as @JonScott already mentioned. Also instance type plays major role in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have an index on column1. If not, then the engine has to scan ALL records starting with the first one until it finds 5 matching records. If you know that more than this single column will match your desired rows and also exclude other rows, you could create a compound index consisting of more than one row. You could also consider partitioning your table.

Comment: Indexes are not an important part of RedShift functionality.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That would be an under-statement. There are **NO** indexes in Redshift. Similar functionality is achieved using sortkeys and distkeys as Jon Scott already commented on question.

Comment: Neither the title nor the question mentions Redshift. There is a tag, though. The title does mention `SQL tuning`, and my answer will be correct in many (most?) SQL flavors. It could be useful to others who find this question.